# Spring Boot Rest Service With Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am writing a Spring Boot Rest Service in Kotlin. I want to use coroutines as an alternative to Webflux to achieve non-blocking asynchronous behavior. I am using Spring Boot 2.1 and know that I cannot achieve true non-blocking behavior because I am blocking at `Controller`. However, I am okay with that for now till the time Spring Boot 2.2 is generally available.

My app is three-layered ie Controller->Service->Repository. In repository, I am calling other services ie network calls and have marked the method as suspend.

I want to ensure if this is the right approach, additionally, does call to suspend fun inside `ResourceService` blocks the caller thread?

Also after reading https://medium.com/@elizarov/blocking-threads-suspending-coroutines-d33e11bf4761 by Roman Elizarov I am not sure if I should use `withContext` along with all of my suspending functions?

```java
package my.springbootapp

import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.asCoroutineDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import mu.KotlinLogging
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

val logger = KotlinLogging.logger { }

@SpringBootApplication
class App

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(App::class.java, *args)
}

@RestController
class Controller(private val resourceService: ResourceService) {
    private val dispatcher = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5).asCoroutineDispatcher()

    @GetMapping("/resource/{id}")
    fun getResource(@PathVariable("id") id: String) = runBlocking(dispatcher) {
        resourceService.get(id).also { logger.info { Thread.currentThread().name + "Returning $it" } }
    }
}

@Service
class ResourceService(private val networkResourceRepository: NetworkResourceRepository) {

    suspend fun get(id: String): Resource {
        logger.info { Thread.currentThread().name + "Getting resource" }
        return networkResourceRepository.get(id)
    }
}

@Repository
class NetworkResourceRepository {
    suspend fun get(id: String): Resource = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        logger.info { Thread.currentThread().name + "Getting resource from n/w" }
        //IO operation
        Resource("resource data")
    }
}

data class Resource(val data: String)
```

Comment: "However, I am okay with that for now till the time Spring Boot 2.2 is generally available." ----> Spring Boot 2.2 was released GA last week, so try that. It's a much better experience.

Comment: Remove `runBlocking` from your endpoint. Every request in SpringBoot is handled in a separate thread anyways. Your `ResourceService` should not expose suspended functions. Make coroutines inside but hide them to outsiders.

Answer (score 2):

I think u should use coroutines with WebFlux but not instead of WebFlux. To use WebFlux with coroutines u must add WebFlux-Wrapper which makes WebFlux suspendable. [WebFlux+Coroutine example](https://spring.io/blog/2019/04/12/going-reactive-with-spring-coroutines-and-kotlin-flow#webflux-with-coroutines-api-in-kotlin)
By itself coroutines will not make your code non-blocking, coroutines goal is that they can just suspend. This wrappers just call some `areYouFinished` method on `WebClient` (for example), if it's not finished coroutine suspends and it will try to call same method in the future(through passing not reached code in future execution).

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked the new documentation on [how to use co-routines](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/languages.html#coroutines) ?

What's interesting for you is that class with @Controller support the following:

- Deferred and Flow return values support in Spring WebFlux
- Suspending function support in Spring WebFlux

So i think you could just use suspend

```
@RestController
class Controller(private val resourceService: ResourceService) {

@GetMapping("/resource/{id}")
suspend fun getResource(@PathVariable("id") id: String) =
        resourceService.get(id).also { logger.info { Thread.currentThread().name + "Returning $it" } }
}
```

Comment: I've ran into getting error on bean creation:
`Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported suspending handler method detected`

maybe u have a clue how to overcome this one?

Comment: you need to provide dependencies used and code